# How to get full domain name of a virtual PC with windows server 2003 installed?

Tags: windows-server-2003, sql-server, active-directory, database

Sorry if it's a noob question.

I now have 3 virtual PCs, which all installed windows server 2003. In order to create an database mirroring demo, I have to know the full domain name of them. These virtual PCs use *Local only* network connection and they see each other.

I tried to create a domain using one of them as domain controller, but then the SQL Server instance on it cannot see these others. I got stuck with that.

How can I do this? A detail tutorial would be great helpful.

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

If these servers are in workgroup mode then they won't have a primary DNS suffix and they won't have a connection specific DNS suffix either, so they won't have a FQDN. They'll have single label NetBIOS names only. You can set the primary or connection specific DNS suffixes to anything you like via computer or NIC properties. You'll still need some type of name resolution mechanism and in this case, I would recommend using the host file on each server.

Answer (score 1):

The WMI class to retrieve that information is win32_computersystem (Dnshostname and domain properties) , however as previously mentioned workgroup systems do not have a primary DNS suffix